# Filter and count in a for loop

Tags: django

In Django (2.0) I'm looping through records to display them in a table, I want a summary count to be displayed at the end for each record, I have this working using `count = Fraction.objects.all().filter(botany_id=13).count()` and the displaying `{{ count }}` however this is setup for record 13, the next record on the row has a botany_id=14 So how do I do this dynamically, essentially botany_id=botany_id

```
#views.py
def allflotation(request):
    botany = Botany.objects.all()
    fraction = Fraction.objects.all()
    count = Fraction.objects.all().filter(botany_id=13).count()
    fractioncomposition = FractionComposition.objects.all()
    # fractionmaterialspresent = FractionMaterialsPresent.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'flotation/allflotation.html',
    {
    'botany':botany,
    'fraction':fraction,
    'count':count,
    'fractioncomposition':fractioncomposition,
    # 'fractionmaterialspresent':fractionmaterialspresent
    })
```

## @@@@@ EDIT

```
#html
...
      <tbody>
    {% for botany in botany.all %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ botany.sample_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ botany.area_easting }}.{{ botany.area_northing }}.{{ botany.context_number }}</td>
      <td>{{ botany.botany_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ botany.sample_number }}</td>
      <td>{{ botany.entry_date }}</td>
      <td>{{ botany.flotation_date }}</td>
      <td>{{ botany.analyst }}</td>
      <td>{{ botany.notes }}</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
          <a href="{% url 'addfraction' pk=botany.botany_id %}">
            <span class="badge badge-primary">
                Add Fraction
              <br />
              <span class="badge badge-light">

                {{ count }}

              </span>
            </span>
          </a>
...
```

changing `{{ count }}` to `{{ botany }}` gives me the botany_id

Answer (score 1):

Using [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager).

views.py

`botanies = Botany.objects.all()`

template.html

```
{% for botany in botanies %}
    {{botany.fraction_set.count}}
{% endfor %}
```

You'll need to optimize number of queries later.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'll add extra info in the question